# What is the best option for calculating any data on large tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework

**The scenario is as follows:**

There is a table with hundreds of businesses, let's say each business creates its own daily data of 100 to 200 rows.

For example, each business receives 150 orders per day. These data are recorded in the database.

At the end of each month, since the size of the data created by the enterprises will enlarge the database, I think the result of the statistical reporting of a business will be longer.

For example, firm A produced 3000 rows of data at the end of the month, while firm B produced 4000 rows.

At the end of the year, the number of rows produced by Company A will be 36000, and the number of rows produced by Company B will be 48000.

When enterprises want to see their monthly earnings and how many sales they make, it doesn't make sense for them to navigate through a database of 84000 rows one by one and calculate the desired data. Because I only gave this example for two businesses, imagine if there were hundreds?

I thought of a solution to this, I want to consult a logical solution, because I do not know how solutions are made in large applications.

While businesses are producing daily data, I can update this statistical report every day by calculating the data they produce and keeping it in a single row in a separate table.

At the end of the month, I think that he can quickly find the relevant line without having to scroll through thousands of lines.

**What is the best option for calculating any data on large tables?**

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, it's true, but what I'm wondering is, when the data table grows and a table has relations with other tables, which scenario is applied in terms of speed?

For example, since the previous month's data will not change after a business's monthly earnings are calculated, the database does not need to calculate it again when the user wants to see the last month's data.

Don't just think of it as a single table, what if the data of multiple tables needs to be calculated as a single row?

Answer (score 0):

In the scheme of things 84000 records is a table is nothing to worry about, you can process that just fine with most RDBMs database engines.  If you are talking about millions of records, then you most likely want to look at Data Warehouse strategies. SQL server has something called Analysis Services which can take your data and create pre-calculated aggregates so that report computations are faster, I expect most database vendors will have something similar.
For transacction processing which is what your original database will use (OLTP - Online Transaction Processing) you want data in 3rd Normal Form.  For analytical purposes (OLAP - Online Analystical Processing) you want de-normalised data as the aggregations can be done faster if you don't need to jump across multiple tables.  Customer->territory->Region and variant->product->type->supertype.

Comment: I'm planning to use a mysql database in my application, so I think the computations will slow down when the database grows, of course with a database of 84000 rows it won't be a problem but when it goes up to a million it can be a problem. I want to take precautions to prevent this from happening, do you think the idea of creating each report in a separate table is correct? A monthly report table and a separate annual report table so that the user can get a quick result whenever he/she wants.